# Configuring problems when moving from http to Https codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, ssl-certificate, cpanel

I have a codeigniter project. Recently I deployed it with SSL. And I forced my site to use Https from http by modifying in .htaccess and changed baseurl too. The problem is I have a registration and login form . When changed from http to Https the form doesn't submits and the entry in dB is also not made...,any thing till I wanna change?

Comment: This is more a hosting issue than programming issue, anyway you should include what you have done to try solve it by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value of base_url in config.php uses https, i.e.

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://example.com/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it because the html try to load non https sources.

You can see the blocked requests on chrome console.

Make sure all your sources (css, js, fonts) are loading with relative urls, anr\or change hard-coded and external links to https